# How to change data for one column in a database?

Tags: mysql

**UPDATE**: I discovered that I was calling the permalink from another table, with the old values.  How can I take the data from the permalinks table and change only the permalinks column in the other table?

```
New id=7005     permalink=beef-ground-85%25-lean-meat-15%25-fat-raw
Old  id=7005    permalink=beef-ground-85pct-lean-meat-_15pct-fat-raw
```

I've done all the stuff in the title, but the old entries keep coming up in local development on my rails app.

List of things I've done.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
rake tmp:cache:clear
rake tmp:clear
clear all browser cookies / cache / sessions
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your update...
This isn't really an answer so much as a comment:  This is exactly why foreign key constraints exist.  However, MySQL's MyISAM table type (the default) does not support them.

A foreign key with an ON UPDATE CASCADE clause would have fixed this automagically for you.